# python sqlite3 select updated row value

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

i want to print the row id of the updated row in the SQL query

```
while True:
  Conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', timeout=60)
  c = Conn.cursor()
  c.execute("UPDATE row SET value='value' where status='status'")
  #i want to do something here to the updated row above
  Conn.commit()
  Conn.close()
```

Comment: This will update all rows in the table `row`. I think you need to be clearer about what you want to return (also why the `while True`?!)

Comment: the while true is because i want it to run always for now 
but what i want exactly is to get the result of that query and know which row id it affected

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two queries (Can slow down your process). One to select IDs and another one to update corresponding IDs

```
while True:
    connection = sqlite3.connect('database.db', timeout=60)
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    # Get IDs to update
    rows = cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM row WHERE status='status'")
    ids = [str(x) for x, in rows]  # Transform tupple list to list of string

    # Update corresponding IDs
    cursor.execute(
        "UPDATE row SET value='value' WHERE id in ({0})".format(','.join(ids)))

    # Do what you want with `ids`...

    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```